# How to access a webservice running on a Win7 PC from an unrooted Android device via USB?

Tags: usb, windows

I have a use case where my app running on an Android device need to communicate with a web service running on a Windows 7 PC. This was achieved using wifi successfully. But now I need to achieve this using USB connection as we may not have wifi working at the customer's location.

The Android device is unrooted. I can not use a reverse tethering app as it needs the device to be rooted.

The following link has the same question but doesn't have an answer - [Accessing localhost of PC from USB connected Android mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887621/accessing-localhost-of-pc-from-usb-connected-android-mobile-device)

Does anybody have an answer for this?

Comment: Accessing localhost of PC from USB connected Android mobile device

Answer (score 0):

I normally do this by using the WiFi tethering option built into Android - and it works perfectly.

As of this moment, the only way you may be able to do it via USB is using ADB, but I have tried using multiple apps and have never got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

To access localhost of PC through USB tethering on android, Do the following:-

1. Assign a static IP to the PC or find the internal IP of the PC.
2. Make sure USB tethering is active.
3. Using stock browser, disable proxies and type in the static IP (internal IP) of the PC.